# Cryptic link error. Where do I start?

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to build the basemap toolkit, from source, for matplotlib to run on my MacBook Pro under OS X 10.8. The C and C++ compiler are those included with the latest Xcode package. The package includes the geos-3.3.3 package which needs to be built separately and installed before the main basemap python package is built. When I do this, using the supplied Makefile, I get the following error when the makefile attempts to build the libgeos.dylib library:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::auto_ptr<geos::geom::Envelope>::auto_ptr(std::auto_ptr_ref<geos::geom::Envelope>)", referenced from:
      virtual thunk to geos::geom::GeometryCollection::computeEnvelopeInternal() constin libgeom.a(GeometryCollection.o)
  "__ZNSt8auto_ptrIN4geos4geom8EnvelopeEEcvSt12auto_ptr_refIT_EIS2_EEv", referenced from:
      virtual thunk to geos::geom::GeometryCollection::computeEnvelopeInternal() constin libgeom.a(GeometryCollection.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

On a Fedora 17 machine, with gcc 4.7, this library builds successfully so there is obviously something going on with the Mac compiler/linker.  However, I have no idea how to decode this message. What, for instance, is a "virtual thunk"? Any insight on how I can compile and build this on the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I used a different compiler and the problem went away. Try:

make CXX=c++

Worked for me. OSX 10.8.3, XCode 4.6.1.